# How do I define reusable link in swagger correctly?

Tags: hyperlink, swagger, openapi

I am using swagger with Open API 3.0.0

Following is my Api definition:

```
paths:
  /offerers:
    get:
      summary: give all offerers back
      operationId: allOfferers
      description: give you all offerers back
      responses:
        '200':
          description: oferers results
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/OfferersId'
          links:
            GetSingleOffererById:
              $ref: '#/components/links/GetSingleOffererById'
        '400':
          description: something went terribly wrong
  /offerers/{offererId}:
    parameters:
      - in: path
        name: offererId
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/OfferersId'
        required: true
    get: 
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OfferersId'
      summary: give one specified offerer back
      operationId: singleOfferer
      description: give one offerer back. Specified by its id
      responses:
        '200':
          description: offerers results
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Offerers'
        '400':
          description: something went terribly wrong

components:
  schemas:
    OfferersId:
      type: number
      example: 123
    Offerers:
      type: object
      required:
        - offererId
        - name
      properties:
        id:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/OfferersId'
        name: 
          type: string
          example: "Mark Mustermann"
        location:
          type: string
          example: "90449 Nürnberg"
        experience:
          type: string
          example: "8 Jahre"
        openingHours:
          type: string
          example: "Werktags: 10:15-18:30/tWochenende: geschlossen."

  links:
    GetSingleOffererById:
      operationId: singleOfferer
      description: the offererId in the response will be used as offererId in the request
      paramters:
        offererId: $reponse.body#/OfferersId
```

Most of this Definition is error free. But the last section components/links gives me an error at line "operationId: singleOfferer":

> should NOT have additional properties additionalProperty: operationId,
>   paramters

So my question:
How do I have to correct my definition, so that the reusable link is valid?

Comment: Typo: `paraMTers` -> `paraMETers`

Comment: # **facepalm** # THANK YOU!!! How do I reward a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"should NOT have additional properties" error in the Swagger Editor usually means one of the following:

1. a keyword is misspelt,
2. syntax/structure is incorrect.

In your example it's (1) - `paraMTers` should be `paraMETers`.